# Failed to validate service from CAS server and it always redirects to CAS server login page

Tags: validation, service, cas

**After the cas app got the the service ticket, cas server redirected to the service with the ticket, then the client generated the service validate to get the response from the server.

The issue is my client fail to reach that service validate url but redirected to the cas server url instead. That means the client will get a HTML response from the server rather than XML response so no principal will be found.**

```
=========================================================================
Logs：

2015-08-21 16:34:22,610 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider] - <serviceUrl = https://localhost/spring-cas/login/cas>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,610 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator] - <Placing URL parameters in map.>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,611 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator] - <Calling template URL attribute map.>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,611 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator] - <Loading custom parameters from configuration.>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,611 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator] - <Constructing validation url: https://localhost/cas/serviceValidate?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,611 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator] - <Retrieving response from server.>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,681 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - <DispatcherServlet with name 'cas' processing GET request for [/login]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,681 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping] - <Mapping request with URI '/login' to flow with id 'login'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,681 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - <Last-Modified value for [/login] is: -1>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,681 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl] - <Launching new execution of flow 'login' with input map['service' -> 'https://localhost/spring-cas/login/cas', 'ticket' -> 'ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org']>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,681 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl] - <Getting FlowDefinition with id 'login'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,681 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImplFactory] - <Creating new execution of 'login'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,681 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.factory.ConditionalFlowExecutionListenerLoader] - <Loaded [1] of possible 1 listeners for this execution request for flow 'login', the listeners to attach are list[org.jasig.cas.web.flow.TerminateWebSessionListener@16bf8a89]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,681 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl] - <Starting in org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.MvcExternalContext@43b29635 with input map['service' -> 'https://localhost/spring-cas/login/cas', 'ticket' -> 'ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org']>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,681 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow] - <Creating [FlowVariable@6b93db25 name = 'credential', valueFactory = [BeanFactoryVariableValueFactory@38189150 type = UsernamePasswordCredential]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,681 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Creating instance of bean 'org.jasig.cas.authentication.UsernamePasswordCredential'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,682 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Finished creating instance of bean 'org.jasig.cas.authentication.UsernamePasswordCredential'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,682 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor] - <Executing [EvaluateAction@1612bb77 expression = initialFlowSetupAction, resultExpression = [null]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,682 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction] - <Putting action execution attributes map[[empty]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,682 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'initialFlowSetupAction'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,682 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor] - <Executing org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction@1d14d2fa>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,682 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.support.CasArgumentExtractor] - <Extractor generated service for: https://localhost/spring-cas/login/cas>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,682 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction] - <Placing service in FlowScope: https://localhost/spring-cas/login/cas>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,682 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor] - <Finished executing org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction@1d14d2fa; result = success>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,682 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction] - <Clearing action execution attributes map[[empty]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,682 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor] - <Finished executing [EvaluateAction@1612bb77 expression = initialFlowSetupAction, resultExpression = [null]]; result = success>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,682 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState] - <Entering state 'ticketGrantingTicketCheck' of flow 'login'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,682 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor] - <Executing [EvaluateAction@2e5467c1 expression = ticketGrantingTicketCheckAction.checkValidity(flowRequestContext), resultExpression = [null]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,682 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction] - <Putting action execution attributes map[[empty]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,682 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'ticketGrantingTicketCheckAction'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,683 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction] - <Clearing action execution attributes map[[empty]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,683 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor] - <Finished executing [EvaluateAction@2e5467c1 expression = ticketGrantingTicketCheckAction.checkValidity(flowRequestContext), resultExpression = [null]]; result = notExists>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,683 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition] - <Executing [Transition@47149705 on = notExists, to = gatewayRequestCheck]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,683 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition] - <Exiting state 'ticketGrantingTicketCheck'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,683 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.DecisionState] - <Entering state 'gatewayRequestCheck' of flow 'login'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,683 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition] - <Executing [Transition@15438447 on = *, to = serviceAuthorizationCheck]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,683 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition] - <Exiting state 'gatewayRequestCheck'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,683 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState] - <Entering state 'serviceAuthorizationCheck' of flow 'login'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,683 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor] - <Executing [EvaluateAction@3a15c39 expression = serviceAuthorizationCheck, resultExpression = [null]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,683 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction] - <Putting action execution attributes map[[empty]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,683 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'serviceAuthorizationCheck'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,683 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor] - <Executing org.jasig.cas.web.flow.ServiceAuthorizationCheck@56ada40b>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,683 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor] - <Finished executing org.jasig.cas.web.flow.ServiceAuthorizationCheck@56ada40b; result = success>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,683 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction] - <Clearing action execution attributes map[[empty]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor] - <Finished executing [EvaluateAction@3a15c39 expression = serviceAuthorizationCheck, resultExpression = [null]]; result = success>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition] - <Executing [Transition@21ecfaa2 on = *, to = generateLoginTicket]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition] - <Exiting state 'serviceAuthorizationCheck'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState] - <Entering state 'generateLoginTicket' of flow 'login'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor] - <Executing [EvaluateAction@4d3ab314 expression = generateLoginTicketAction.generate(flowRequestContext), resultExpression = [null]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction] - <Putting action execution attributes map[[empty]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'generateLoginTicketAction'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.GenerateLoginTicketAction] - <Generated login ticket LT-3-rE1DVbEXOgxDMeLVe5LtdtDfDPVN75-cas01.example.org>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction] - <Clearing action execution attributes map[[empty]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor] - <Finished executing [EvaluateAction@4d3ab314 expression = generateLoginTicketAction.generate(flowRequestContext), resultExpression = [null]]; result = generated>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition] - <Executing [Transition@48c30da8 on = generated, to = viewLoginForm]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition] - <Exiting state 'generateLoginTicket'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState] - <Entering state 'viewLoginForm' of flow 'login'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor] - <Executing [SetAction@7db5b5e9 name = viewScope.commandName, value = 'credential']>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction] - <Putting action execution attributes map[[empty]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction] - <Clearing action execution attributes map[[empty]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,684 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor] - <Finished executing [SetAction@7db5b5e9 name = viewScope.commandName, value = 'credential']; result = success>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,685 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.SessionBindingConversationManager] - <Putting conversation attribute 'name' with value login>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,685 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.SessionBindingConversationManager] - <Putting conversation attribute 'caption' with value null>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,685 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.SessionBindingConversationManager] - <Putting conversation attribute 'description' with value null>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,685 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.SessionBindingConversationManager] - <Putting conversation attribute 'flowExecutionSnapshotGroup' with value org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.SimpleFlowExecutionSnapshotGroup@4edccdb9>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,685 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl] - <Assigned key e1s1>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,685 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState] - <Rendering + [ServletMvcView@2465522 view = org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'casLoginView'; URL [/WEB-INF/view/jsp/default/ui/casLoginView.jsp]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,685 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState] - <  Flash scope = map[[empty]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,685 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState] - <  Messages = [DefaultMessageContext@577f2c58 sourceMessages = map[[null] -> list[[empty]]]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,685 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView] - <Rendering MVC [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'casLoginView'; URL [/WEB-INF/view/jsp/default/ui/casLoginView.jsp]] with model map [{flowRequestContext=[RequestControlContextImpl@119ca5d3 externalContext = org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.MvcExternalContext@43b29635, currentEvent = generated, requestScope = map[[empty]], attributes = map[[empty]], messageContext = [DefaultMessageContext@577f2c58 sourceMessages = map[[null] -> list[[empty]]]], flowExecution = [FlowExecutionImpl@434ac8ad flow = 'login', flowSessions = list[[FlowSessionImpl@62bcf85e flow = 'login', state = 'viewLoginForm', scope = map['loginTicket' -> 'LT-3-rE1DVbEXOgxDMeLVe5LtdtDfDPVN75-cas01.example.org', 'service' -> https://localhost/spring-cas/login/cas, 'warnCookieValue' -> false, 'ticketGrantingTicketId' -> [null], 'credential' -> null+password, 'viewScope' -> map['commandName' -> 'credential']]]]]], flashScope=map[[empty]], org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.credential=org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.BindingModel: 0 errors, currentUser=null, loginTicket=LT-3-rE1DVbEXOgxDMeLVe5LtdtDfDPVN75-cas01.example.org, service=https://localhost/spring-cas/login/cas, commandName=credential, flowExecutionKey=e1s1, warnCookieValue=false, flowExecutionUrl=/login;jsessionid=C905A5283738DA68A18E4C78C0D68A81?ticket=%5BLjava.lang.String%3B%405e387248&service=%5BLjava.lang.String%3B%404bd7054b&execution=e1s1, credential=null+password, ticketGrantingTicketId=null, viewScope=map['commandName' -> 'credential']}]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,685 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - <Added model object 'flowRequestContext' of type [org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl] to request in view with name 'casLoginView'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,686 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - <Added model object 'flashScope' of type [org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap] to request in view with name 'casLoginView'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,686 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - <Added model object 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.credential' of type [org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.BindingModel] to request in view with name 'casLoginView'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,686 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - <Removed model object 'currentUser' from request in view with name 'casLoginView'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,686 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - <Added model object 'loginTicket' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'casLoginView'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,686 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - <Added model object 'service' of type [org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.SimpleWebApplicationServiceImpl] to request in view with name 'casLoginView'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,686 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - <Added model object 'commandName' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'casLoginView'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,686 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - <Added model object 'flowExecutionKey' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'casLoginView'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,686 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - <Added model object 'warnCookieValue' of type [java.lang.Boolean] to request in view with name 'casLoginView'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,686 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - <Added model object 'flowExecutionUrl' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'casLoginView'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,686 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - <Added model object 'credential' of type [org.jasig.cas.authentication.UsernamePasswordCredential] to request in view with name 'casLoginView'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,686 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - <Removed model object 'ticketGrantingTicketId' from request in view with name 'casLoginView'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,686 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - <Added model object 'viewScope' of type [org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap] to request in view with name 'casLoginView'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,686 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - <Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/view/jsp/default/ui/casLoginView.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'casLoginView'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,687 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.support.CasArgumentExtractor] - <Extractor generated service for: https://localhost/spring-cas/login/cas>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition] - <Completed transition execution.  As a result, the new state is 'viewLoginForm' in flow 'login'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition] - <Completed transition execution.  As a result, the new state is 'viewLoginForm' in flow 'login'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition] - <Completed transition execution.  As a result, the new state is 'viewLoginForm' in flow 'login'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition] - <Completed transition execution.  As a result, the new state is 'viewLoginForm' in flow 'login'>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.SessionBindingConversationManager] - <Locking conversation 1>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository] - <Putting flow execution '[FlowExecutionImpl@434ac8ad flow = 'login', flowSessions = list[[FlowSessionImpl@62bcf85e flow = 'login', state = 'viewLoginForm', scope = map['loginTicket' -> 'LT-3-rE1DVbEXOgxDMeLVe5LtdtDfDPVN75-cas01.example.org', 'service' -> https://localhost/spring-cas/login/cas, 'warnCookieValue' -> false, 'ticketGrantingTicketId' -> [null], 'credential' -> null+password, 'viewScope' -> map['commandName' -> 'credential']]]]]' into repository>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository] - <Adding snapshot to group with id 1>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,691 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.SessionBindingConversationManager] - <Putting conversation attribute 'scope' with value map['flashScope' -> map['messagesMemento' -> map[[empty]]]]>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,691 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.SessionBindingConversationManager] - <Unlocking conversation 1>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,691 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - <Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'cas': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,691 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - <Successfully completed request>
2015-08-21 16:34:22,696 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator] - <Server response: 

<!DOCTYPE html>








<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <title>CAS &#8211; Central Authentication Service</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/cas.css;jsessionid=C905A5283738DA68A18E4C78C0D68A81" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico;jsessionid=C905A5283738DA68A18E4C78C0D68A81" type="image/x-icon" />

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.1/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="cas">
  <div id="container">
      <header>
        <a id="logo" href="http://www.jasig.org" title="go to Jasig home page">Jasig</a>
        <h1>Central Authentication Service (CAS)</h1>
      </header>
      <div id="content">




<div class="box" id="login">
  <form id="fm1" action="/login;jsessionid=C905A5283738DA68A18E4C78C0D68A81?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas" method="post">



    <h2>Enter your Username and Password</h2>

    <section class="row">
      <label for="username"><span class="accesskey">U</span>sername:</label>




          <input id="username" name="username" class="required" tabindex="1" accesskey="u" type="text" value="" size="25" autocomplete="off"/>


    </section>

    <section class="row">
      <label for="password"><span class="accesskey">P</span>assword:</label>


      <input id="password" name="password" class="required" tabindex="2" accesskey="p" type="password" value="" size="25" autocomplete="off"/>
    </section>

    <section class="row check">
      <input id="warn" name="warn" value="true" tabindex="3" accesskey="w" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="warn"><span class="accesskey">W</span>arn me before logging me into other sites.</label>
    </section>

    <section class="row btn-row">
      <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="LT-3-rE1DVbEXOgxDMeLVe5LtdtDfDPVN75-cas01.example.org" />
      <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="e1s1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="submit" />

      <input class="btn-submit" name="submit" accesskey="l" value="LOGIN" tabindex="4" type="submit" />
      <input class="btn-reset" name="reset" accesskey="c" value="CLEAR" tabindex="5" type="reset" />
    </section>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-content">
    <p>For security reasons, please Log Out and Exit your web browser when you are done accessing services that require authentication!</p>

    <div id="list-languages">




      <h3>Languages:</h3>





          <ul>
            <li class="first"><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=en">English</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=es">Spanish</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=fr">French</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=ru">Russian</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=nl">Nederlands</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=sv">Svenska</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=it">Italiano</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=ur">Urdu</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=zh_CN">Chinese (Simplified)</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=zh_TW">Chinese (Traditional)</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=de">Deutsch</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=ja">Japanese</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=hr">Croatian</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=cs">Czech</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=sl">Slovenian</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=ca">Catalan</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=mk">Macedonian</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=fa">Farsi</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=ar">Arabic</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=pt_PT">Portuguese</a></li>
            <li><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=pt_BR">Portuguese (Brazil)</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="login?ticket=ST-1-fQ3f56nLJkjS54aeQgd9-cas01.example.org&amp;service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fspring-cas%2Flogin%2Fcas&locale=pl">Polish</a></li>
          </ul>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>




      </div> <!-- END #content -->

      <footer>
        <div id="copyright">
          <p>Copyright &copy; 2005&ndash;2012 Jasig, Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
          <p>Powered by <a href="http://www.jasig.org/cas">Jasig Central Authentication Service 4.0.4</a></p>
        </div>
      </footer>

    </div> <!-- END #container -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/cowboy/javascript-debug/raw/master/ba-debug.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/cas.js;jsessionid=C905A5283738DA68A18E4C78C0D68A81"></script>
  </body>
</html>


>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question what you raised is not so clear to me, any how i just want to share some suggestions, First we need to send username and password to our (actual or parent) application which will redirect (using CAS clients) to cas server along with serviceId and Ticket, CAS server will authenticate that, and returns back AuthenticatedId, For this purpose we must use the same https certificate in both you application level and CAS server level, then only it will accept the request.

Comment: For service validation, the client should go to the generated service validate url of the CAS server to valiate, but the problem is the server always redirects to its login page, but not validate the service through its servicevaliate controller. I don't know why...